# How to center that div ? (Carousel/OWL JS/Boostrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I've been trying for HOURS to center a simple div with text into a slider.
https://cdpn.io/alouwk/debug/vYLLjwM/XxkVwjBPGEGM

I'm just looking for a way to always center the text, without losing the responsive ability of it.
I tried every possible answers I found online, without any success.
By the way, I'm a super noob with Bootstrap (never used it), and was just trying to edit a slider from this tutorial : https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-full-screen-responsive-carousel-slider-with-owljs--cms-31771

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: do you have access for the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">` as you can see you should remove the `justify-content-md-start` it will be centered and if you dont have access for the html you can override it by targeting the class `justify-content-md-start{justify-content:center!important;}`

Comment: Holy hell, it worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH ! I wish your were my godfather.

Comment: @S.Bnstan :) glad to hear that plz dont forget to accept the answer